# Building the Pyspark sytax dynamically

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

We have a requirement where we need to save the ETL operations rules in mysql database and run the AWS glue job based on the rules coded in Pyspark.

we are going to save the actual Pysaprk syntax in the rules table as string like below.

s.no|rule|output

1|df1.join(df2, on=['age'], how='right_outer')|df3

2|df3.join(df4, on=['age'], how='right_outer')|df5

3|df5.join(df6, on=['age'], how='right_outer')|df7

we are going to pull this from DB and store it as DF.

For i in DF:

i.output = i.rule

#after substituting the value it look like (df3 = df1.join(df2, on=['age'], how='right_outer') )

But the join operation is not happening. Since the values are stored as string in the DB its just substituting the values.

Please help me here what needs to be changed for the join operations to be executed.do i need to change the data type?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
df_all = df1.join(df2, on=['age'], how='right_outer')\
            .join(df3, on=['age'], how='right_outer')\
            .join(df4, on=['age'], how='right_outer')

df_all.show()
```

Best,